# Confused about FULLTEXT search in Boolean Mode when wildcard is used

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, wildcard

I'm experiencing weird results when using the boolean mode. I have the following table:

```sql
create table articles(
    id    bigint auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(255) null)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    default charset = utf8mb4;

create fulltext index articles_full_idx_subtitle
    on articles (subtitle);
```

on MySQL 8.0.34 (innoDB engine,  innodb_ft_min_token_size = 3)

If I execute the following search

```
select title from articles where match(title) against ('c!ia*' in boolean mode) -- or 'c/ia*', 'c$ia*',...
```

I have the very same results as using 'c*'...which is strange, because as far as I have understood the fulltext search, I was expecting that 'c!ia*' would be equivalent to 'ia*'. ! is a delimiter and c is a single char token which is neglected.

Do you have any explanation about it? I'm probably missing something, but I couldn't figure it out.